# Prototype inner wrap

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, javascript-framework

I have searched the documentation and tried various techniques but have't found a suitable technique to achieve the following dom manipulation:

```
<h3>hello</h3>
```

to

```
<h3><a href="#">hello</a></h3>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Prototype has no equivalent to jQuery's `wrapInner()`. You can, however, simulate it with [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML):

```
$$("h3").each(function(element) {
    element.replace("<h3><a href='#'>" + element.innerHTML + "</a></h3>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototype's [`wrap`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/wrap/) does actually work on text nodes, but it doesn't say that clearly, nor are text nodes extended in the usual way. Also the `$$` selector excludes native text nodes so you need to fetch them yourself.

```
var h3 = $$('h3').first(),
    text = h3.childNodes.first();
Element.wrap(text, 'a', { href: '#' });
```